When is the pairwise product of $m$ integers and $n$ integers a complete residue system?
Given $m$ integers $a_1,\cdots,a_m$ and $n$ integers $b_1,\cdots,b_n$. Suppose that the set of all $mn$ products of integer pairs $\{a_ib_j\}_{i,j}$ form a complete residue system modulo $mn$, what can we say about $m,n$ and $\{a_i\}_i,\{b_j\}_j$? To be more precise, there are three interesting problems:

For which pair $(m,n)$, the set of integers $\{a_i\}_i,\{b_j\}_j$ exist?

Do both $\{a_i\}_i,\{b_j\}_j$ form complete residue systems modulo $m,n$? Or at least one of them is a complete system?

Could we somehow give a classification of all possible sets $\{a_i\}_i,\{b_j\}_j$ for given $m,n$?


I try to understand the case where $m,n$ are both primes. It is easy to see that $m\ne n$. If not, since the $m^2$ products have exactly $m$ multiples of $m$, so there must be a unique multiple of $m$ in $\{a_i\}\cup\{b_j\}$. Suppose $m\mid a_1$ and $m\nmid b_j$, then by the Pigeonhole Principle there are $b_{j_1}\equiv b_{j_2}\bmod m$, so $a_1b_{j_1}\equiv a_1b_{j_2}\bmod m^2$.
So $m\ne n$ are different primes. It is similar to find that only one of $a_i$ is a multiple of $m$ and only one of $b_j$ is a multiple of $n$ and none of them is a multiple of $mn$. Set $m\mid a_1,n\mid b_1,n\nmid a_1,m\nmid b_1$. In a complete system modulo $mn$, the multiples of $m$ have different residues modulo $n$. So $\{a_1b_j\}_j$ is complete system modulo $n$. Hence $\{b_j\}_j$ is a complete system. Similarly $\{a_i\}_i$ is complete too.
Now given the more general case where $\mathrm{GCD}(m,n)=1$ are two coprime numbers. We have a construction by Chinese Remainder Theorem:
$$a_i\equiv i\bmod m, a_i\equiv 1\bmod n;\\ b_j\equiv 1\bmod m, b_j\equiv j\bmod n. $$
So $a_ib_j\equiv i\bmod m,a_ib_j\equiv j\bmod n$.
